# Mock only one call on api

Tags: android, mocking, retrofit, retrofit2

I have several calls, login, search, and need to mock only one call on api.
This is because the api that I need to call is not ready, but login, search is ready.
I've seen it on several forums, but all examples show Intercepting all the flames.
I'm using Retrofit with Android to make the calls.

Comment: Are you saying you want to intercept the Retrofit request and return a mock response for that particular api?

Comment: You can use mockio. https://www.mocky.io/   Here, you can get a mock respoonse but i dont think you will be able to mock the payload to be sent.

Comment: @hjchin Yes, I already have api ready, I need to simulate only a specific api

Comment: @Duk any update on this? Interested to see this